# Preact : How to get url params from one component to another

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, preact

I want to pass some info from one .tsx file to another (one view to another) by clicking a link. How can I achieve this in Preact.

Main.tsx

```
<Router onChange={(r) => setTitle(getTitle(r))}
                        routes={{
                            '/': <RouteComponent component={ContactForm} />,
                            '/faq/:user?': <RouteComponent component={Faq} />
                        }} />
```

ContactForm.tsx

```
<RouteLink href={`/faq/Jason`} > here</RouteLink>
```

Faq.tsx

```
const Faq = ({ user, ...props }) => {
    console.log(user);
    ...
```

My ContactForm.tsx is loading correctly but clicking on a link on that page, I believe, its not going to Faq.tsx. It takes me to Faq.tsx if I remove the query parameters but I need to pass the name 'Jason' from ContactForm.tsx to faq.tsx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be achievable with the current version of preact-router, which comes with Preact. It looks like you're using an older version, or at least a different structure to what's described [here](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-router). Try following that example :)

Answer (score -1):

`const  user = this.props.match.params.user`

Comment: Please add some description also.

Comment: This didnot help me. Nothing happens.

Answer (score -2):

Yo ucan find the param on the routing params. Use this:

```
const { user } = useParams();
```

See here: https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/

Comment: I tried to install "react-router-dom" module but it says : "cannot find module react". Here are my imports : import { h, Fragment } from 'preact';
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'preact/hooks';
import { ServiceContext } from '../AppContext';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { RouteLink } from '../layout/Router';
import { useTimeout } from '../hooks';

Comment: This answer assumes you're using React, not Preact. It looks like you can use React Router with Preact, by aliasing it to "React" and installing preact-compat, but that's probably not the simplest answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306197/how-to-use-react-router-with-preact